# how do i add a json body to my axios post request?

Tags: reactjs, api, axios

```
  submitForm = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    sessionStorage.setItem('username', this.state.username);
    sessionStorage.setItem('password', this.state.password);

    axios.post('/authenticate', {data: {
      username: sessionStorage.getItem('username'),
      password: sessionStorage.getItem('password')
    }})
    .then((response) => {
       this.setState({
         jwttoken: response.data
       })
     },
     sessionStorage.setItem('token', this.state.jwttoken)
     )
```

this is my post request but it does not seem to work
i need to add a username and password in the body,
am i doing it right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try it;

```
const url = Your url
const { username, password } = this.state
const data = {
    username,
    password
}
axios.post(url, data)
...
```